# Typescript type error - Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel, supabase

I'm working on a Next.js project. I use Typescript and .tsx files. I use Supabase as db.

I'm unable to build the project in Vercel even if everything works perfectly on localhost.

The error I get is : `Type error: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

My question is: It seems that I'm correctly pushing a string[] value (ie `["value1", "value2", "value3"]`) but what's the 'string' from the error message the string[] variable is trying to be assigned to?

Here's the code:

```
export default function UserPreferences() {

    const [tags, setTags] = useState<string[]>([]);

    ...

    const handleSubmitPreferences = async (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            if (user) {
                await PreferencesToSupabase(user.id, tags)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred:', error);
        }
    };

    ...

    async function PreferencesToSupabase(user_id: string, preferences: string | null) {

        const { error } = await supabaseClient
            .from('userpreferences')
            .upsert([
                { user_id: user_id, pref: preferences }
            ], { onConflict: ['user_id'], updateColumns: ['pref', 'updated_at'] });

        if (err) {
            throw error;
        }

    ...

    }


}
```

Here's the error I have :

```
Type error: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  263 |             .upsert([
  264 |                 { user_id: user_id, pref: preferences }
> 265 |             ], { onConflict: ['user_id'], updateColumns: ['pref', 'updated_at'] });
      |                  ^
  266 |
```

my colum `pref` in Supabase is of type `text[]` and an example of value it stores is : `["value1", "value2", "value3"]`.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onConflict` only accepts a single column name, you're passing it a `string[]`